# Gallery with thumbnail carousel

Tags: images, gallery, thumbnails

first post so hopefully I don't break any rules! :P

I'm in the process of building a Wordpress theme for the Architecture office I work in. I am creating a page template to use for individual jobs and am a bit swamped by all the galleries, jQuery etc out there. Basically I want to do what [this firm](http://arhitekturakrusec.si/en/) has done with their photos. Requirements:

- Clean, minimalist style. Although I'm proficient with CSS so can probably tidy up any solution that way.
- Horizontal thumbnails along bottom.
- Fixed main image 'container' size.
- Easyish method of adding photos to a gallery and gallery to site (I won't always be the one adding pics).

There are a few other considerations but basically I'm just after some pointers to get me going in the right direction, I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed just now. I'll be able to discuss this further once I have some ideas from you guys of what's realistically the best route.

I was trying to look into using nextgen to create galleries etc, then jQuery on the front end, but I'm pretty far out of my depth. Once I know the best solution I'm pretty good at teaching myself how to implement it, so hopefully that'll work in this case too!!

Hope that wasn't too long winded, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: do not discover a bicycle, there a lot of galleries. For example very good gallery http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/

Comment: Take a look at this solution that uses jCarousel: http://bertanha.com.br/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, thanks very much for your advice. I've managaed to find something approaching what I was looking for with the GalleryView [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-nextgen-galleryview/) for NextGen. It doesn't have the look I was after, but I'm comfortable to style that in CSS myself.

It was mainly the answers on here that got me a bit more on the right track, so thanks again. I have another question regarding posting the gallery in a specific place in a template file, but I think that should be answered in a new question if I understand correctly!

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I am biased, because I wrote it, but Portfolio Slideshow sounds like exactly what you're looking for. It's clean and minimal and integrates with the native WP media tools. The free version includes rows of thumbnails, if you need a carousel, it's available in the paid upgrade.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/portfolio-slideshow

Dalton